# Apache Shiro - SecurityManager es estático o es creado en cada petición?

Tags: java, apache-shiro

He estado analizando el funcionamiento de este framework a fin de entender su funcionamiento pero me he topado con lo siguiente:

El objeto principal que es el `SecurityManager` el cual es encargado de toda la seguridad, ¿es creado en cada petición? o, ¿es un objeto estático que se crea al inicio de la aplicación?

No comprendo por qué el `SecurityManager` se toma del `ThreadContext` como un objeto que hace parte de la petición.

Lo que se establece en el `ThreadContext.bind(SecurityManager sm)`, ¿es solo una referencia al `SecurityManager` creado al inicio de la aplicación? o, ¿es en sí, una nueva instancia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un SecurityManager es un objeto que te permite autenticar, autorizar y gestionar la sesión desde un unico punto. Es un interface y tiene distintas implementacion (AuthenticatingSecurityManager, AuthorizingSecurityManager, CachingSecurityManager, DefaultSecurityManager, DefaultWebSecurityManager, RealmSecurityManager, SessionsSecurityManager) y solo esta asociado a un unico Subject, cada Subject puede tener un distinto SecurityManager... o no, es lo tienes que decider tu.

Por otro lado, Shiro no asocia un Subject al Thread en curso, esto se puede hacer de forma automática, manual o en otro Thread. Cada uno tiene su forma de hacerse, en http://shiro.apache.org/subject.html puedes ver mas detalles al respecto.

Lo que hace ThreadContext es asociar información de contexto a un Thread, como es el SecurityManager a utilizar entre otras, incluso puedes añadir información de contexto adicional